# How do you "OR" criteria together when using a criteria query with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to do a basic "OR" on three fields using a hibernate criteria query.

Example

```
class Whatever{
 string name;
 string address;
 string phoneNumber;
}
```

I'd like to build a criteria query where my search string could match "name" or "address" or "phoneNumber".

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You want to use `Restrictions.disjuntion()`. Like so

```
session.createCriteria(Whatever.class)
    .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
        .add(Restrictions.eq("name", queryString))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("address", queryString))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("phoneNumber", queryString))
    );
```

See the Hibernate doc [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing).

Comment: That is perfect thanks! I finally found an example online, but I'm glad it's here for future reference.

Comment: what if I wanted `(name = x AND address = y) OR (phoneNumber = z)`?

Answer (score 73):

Assuming you have a hibernate session to hand then something like the following should work:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Whatever.class);
Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
or.add(Restrictions.eq("name",searchString));
or.add(Restrictions.eq("address",searchString));
or.add(Restrictions.eq("phoneNumber",searchString));
c.add(or);
```

Comment: I do like the syntax of creating the Disjunction and naming it or. It's a lot more readable than the other solution.

Comment: This was great :) Also agree with @ScArcher2, it is very readable and made the more complicated example I had to do much easier to understand.

Answer (score 12):

```
    //Expression :  (c1 AND c2) OR (c3)      


     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);

      Criterion c1 = Restrictions.like("name", "%e%");
      Criterion c2 = Restrictions.ge("salary", 10000.00);
      Criterion c3 = Restrictions.like("name", "%YYY%");
      Criterion c4 = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.and(c1, c2), c3);
      criteria.add(c4);
```

//Same thing can be done for (c1 OR c2) AND c3, or any complex expression.

Answer (score 6):

```
//Expression :  (c1 AND c2) OR (c3)      


 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);

  Criterion c1 = Restrictions.like("name", "%e%");
  Criterion c2 = Restrictions.ge("salary", 10000.00);
  Criterion c3 = Restrictions.like("name", "%YYY%");
  Criterion c4 = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.and(c1, c2), c3);
  criteria.add(c4);

  //Same thing can be done for (c1 OR c2) AND c3, or any complex expression.
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone should stumble upon this with the same question for NHibernate:

```
ICriteria c = session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Whatever))
    .Add(Expression.Disjunction()
        .Add(Expression.Eq("name", searchString))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("address", searchString))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("phoneNumber", searchString)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions can be applied using the or / and in different levels of the query
using disjunction

```
Criteria query = getCriteria("ENTITY_NAME");
query.add(Restrictions.ne("column Name", current _value));

Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();

if (param_1 != null)
    disjunction.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("column Name", param1)));

if (param_2 != null)
    disjunction.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("column Name", param_2)));

if (param_3 != null)
    disjunction.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("column Name", param_3)));
if (param_4 != null && param_5 != null)
    disjunction.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("column Name", param_4 ), Restrictions.eq("column Name", param_5 ))));

if (disjunction.conditions() != null && disjunction.conditions().iterator().hasNext())
    query.add(Restrictions.and(disjunction));

return query.list();
```

Comment: is it possible to get null for all the elements not found in the db?

Comment: It is consistant: a list is returned with all results, whether there are any or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me for an OR condition, that too with an IN condition and not the answer up-voted most on this discussion:

```
criteria.add( Restrictions.or(
                    Restrictions.eq(ch.getPath(ch.propertyResolver().getXXXX()), "OR_STRING"),
                        Restrictions.in(ch.getPath(ch.propertyResolver().getYYYY()), new String[]{"AA","BB","CC"})
                    ));
```

**Resulting Query:**

```
  and (
            this_.XXXX=? 
            or this_.YYYY in (
                ?, ?, ?
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is using CriteriaQuery instead of Criteria, you can put all your expressions in a `Predicate` list and put a OR by predicates size like this:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
if (...) {
  predicates.add(...);
}

criteriaQuery.where(cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
```