# sql hibernate and or restrictions

Tags: c#, sql, hibernate, restrictions

my sql should look like this:

```
select cell1 from table
where cell2 = 1
and (cell3 = '' or cell3 is null)
```

But how to do the "and ( x or y )" restricion with hibernate?

Comment: Possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484/how-do-you-or-criteria-together-when-using-a-criteria-query-with-hibernate

Comment: @tostao: Not really. The question you linked is referring to Hibernate's Criteria OR mechanism, while this question refers to Hibernate OR in general (e.g. HQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [LogicalExpression](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/LogicalExpression.html)

Try this for **AND** condition:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(table.class);

// To get records matching with AND condistions
LogicalExpression andExp = Restrictions.and(cell2, cell3);
cr.add( andExp );
```

For **OR** condition use this

```
 // To get records matching with OR condistions
  LogicalExpression orExp = Restrictions.or(cell2, cell3);
  cr.add( orExp );

 List results = cr.list();
```