# Multiple OR in hibernate restrictions using disjunction or in for the same field

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, restrictions

I'm trying to come up with a criteria that would check whether or not a certain string is one of a number of possible patterns.

e.g. `myField` should not conform to any of the following patterns: `pattern1%`, `pattern2%`, `pattern3%`

If I were to do this one at a time, the restriction would look something like

```
criteria.add( Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("myField", "pattern1%")) )
```

for each of the patterns. Since there are several, I thought of trying out the `disjunction` restriction from hibernate like the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484/how-do-you-or-criteria-together-when-using-a-criteria-query-with-hibernate). For example's sake, let's just say I'm not using patterns and am equating to a series of fixed strings. So I was hoping for something like:

```
criteria.add(
   Restrictions.disjunction()
      .add(Restrictions.like("myField", "str1"))
      .add(Restrictions.like("myField", "str2"))
)
```

But, for some reason, this doesn't work. When I changed it to:

```
criteria.add( 
   Restrictions.disjunction()
      .add(Restrictions.like("myField", "str1"))
      .add(Restrictions.like("anotherField", "str2"))
)
```

it does, so I wasn't sure if it's because disjunction won't permit multiple conditions to the same field. However, samples [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) in section 15.2 show otherwise with the "age" field.

Hence, at the moment, I'm forced to use

```
criteria.add(
   Restrictions.in("myField", new String[] {"str1", "str2"})
)
```

which only solves half my problem since I need patterns to be in there somewhere.

So my question is, is it possible to use disjunction or in to check if a string matches any of the patterns that may be defined? If so, how? Or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(
                Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("myField", "str1"),
                        Restrictions.like("myField", "str1"))));
```

Or if there is some pattern you are looking for then this should work:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(
                    Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("myField", "%"+"str1"),
                            Restrictions.like("myField", "str1"+"%"))));
```

Hope this helps..!!!