# How to use AND SqlRestriction which contains OR condition inside?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm facing problems in using Restrictions. I've a table `employee` which has following structure :

```
id : int (primary key)
create_date : datetime
modified_date: datetime
```

I'm using following code to list down an employee if it's created/modified within a particular time interval :

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", employeeId));

if (interval > 0) {
     String sql = "{alias}.create_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " + interval + " SECOND) OR {alias}.modified_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " + interval + " SECOND)";
     criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(sqlWhere));
}

List<Employee> employeeList = criteria.list();
```

Please note that there is a OR condition inside the SqlRestriction.

Now suppose `employeeId = 10` and `interval = 3600`, the `employeeList` contains other employees along with id=10 which should not happen.

Should I use `Restrictions.and` or `Restrictions.conjunction` to solve it ? Or I'm missing something else ?

Comment: Try out this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484/how-do-you-or-criteria-together-when-using-a-criteria-query-with-hibernate

Comment: @user4246662 : I had gone through that prior to posting. I see it's about OR'ing the restrictions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic here.  Use Restrictions.and method to group two criterion.  Hibernate should automatically group subqueries to achieve the desired results.

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);

Criterion whereClause = Restrictions.eq("id", employeeId);
if (interval > 0) {
    String sql = "{alias}.create_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " + interval + " SECOND) OR {alias}.modified_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " + interval + " SECOND)";
    Criterion andConjunction = Restrictions.and(
        whereClause, 
        Restrictions.sqlRestriction(sqlWhere)
    );

    whereClause = andConjunction;
}
criteria.add(whereClause);

List<Employee> employeeList = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. I'm testing with `Restrictions.conjunction` which also giving the desired result. Is there any difference between these two ?

Comment: @blackSmith Restrictions.conjunction returns what in a sense should be considered a List of Criterion joined by AND allowing you to have more than two.  Not that you couldn't do the same with Restrictions.and, but you'd have to call it n - 1 times where n is the number of conditions.  So in summary, no, it works the same way.  It just makes it more convenient to write out if you have a lot of conditions joined with AND or OR (disjunction).